# I am having errors with Django authenticated built-in function

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have been woking in django for a while. Now i am facing some problems with built-in function in django. The error state that **TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable**. This kind of error happened because of statement 'print(request.user.is_authenticated())'. 
 Here below is source code:

```
def login_page(request):
form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
#ensure user is logged in or not
print(request.user.is_authenticated())
if form.is_valid():
    print(form.cleaned_data)

return render(request,"auth/login.html",{})
```

For LoginForm() is imported by my file forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
   #first will be name which is variable
    fullname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput
        (attrs={"class":"form-control","placeholder":"Your fullname"}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput
        (attrs={"class":"form-control","placeholder":"Your Email"}))
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea
        (attrs={"class":"form-control","placeholder":"Your content"}))

    def clean_email(self):
       email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
       if not "gmail.com" in email:
          raise forms.ValidationError("Email has to be gmail.com")
       #return value of email to be stored
       return email
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()
```

Answer (score 0):

yes what you want to do is:

```
print(request.user.is_authenticated)
```

without () because it is an built-in function

Comment: Now, it is working now. For my confusion that `is_authenticate()` is built-in function

Answer (score 0):

[`is_authenticated` is an attribute of the`User` model, not a method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated).

So, drop the method reference:

```
print(request.user.is_authenticated)
```

Comment: Now, it is working now. For my confusion that `is_authenticate()` is built-in function